# PATH error: "not a valid identifier"

Tags: bash, path, bin, iterm

I had to get a new hard drive on my Mac and in setting up my developer environment, I'm getting this error/message in the terminal (iTerm2):

-bash: unset: `PATH=/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/Users/(mycomputername)/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/(mycomputername)/bin': not a valid identifier

From what I've been able to research myself so far, it *might* be related to installing node using brew. (I could be wrong.)

FYI:

which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

which node
/usr/local/bin/node

which python
/usr/local/bin/python

Also, I'm using these instructions to set up. I'm aware a few things in this list are out of date:

https://github.com/nicolashery/mac-dev-setup

**EDIT**:

*Contents of ~/.bash_profile*:

```
# Add Homebrew /usr/local/bin and User ~/bin to the $PATH 

PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH 
export PATH 

# Load the shell dotfiles, and then some: # * ~/.path can be used to extend $PATH. 
# * ~/.extra can be used for other settings you don’t want to commit. 

for file in ~/.{path,bash_prompt,exports,aliases,functions,extra}; 
    do [ -r "$file" ] && source "$file" 
done 

unset fileexport PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH" 
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/sbin:$PATH"
```

Comment: How/where is the `unset` being command issued?

Comment: Post the output of `~/.bash_profile` (eg. `cat ~/.bash_profile`)

Comment: # Add Homebrew `/usr/local/bin` and User `~/bin` to the `$PATH`
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH

# Load the shell dotfiles, and then some:
# * ~/.path can be used to extend `$PATH`.
# * ~/.extra can be used for other settings you don’t want to commit.
for file in ~/.{path,bash_prompt,exports,aliases,functions,extra}; do
  [ -r "$file" ] && source "$file"
done
unset fileexport PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/sbin:$PATH"

Comment: [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

Comment: It's probably this line `unset fileexport PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"`... comment it out by adding `#` in front of it, then re-save the file. Then close `iTerm2`, relaunch it and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Please add code to your question, not into a comment - it makes it very difficult to read and we can't see where line breaks occur.

Comment: You are probably doing `unset $PATH` instead of `unset PATH`.

Comment: Thank you, @l'L'l. That did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is this line in your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
unset fileexport PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"
```

comment it out with `#` and restart `iTerm2`